# How can I get an option to always be executed last?

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm using getopts to deal with parameters.
I need to have an option that has to be always executed last.
Let's say i have option a,b,c,d,e, I need e to always be last.
How would I do that?

Comment: set a flag and check it in the other options

Comment: I don't know about flags. Could you give me an example?

Comment: under `e` do `lastopt=1`, check for that value in the other options, if it is set, then do whatever.